# ASP.NET MVC как лучше передать Response с Header,в котором есть русские символы?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http

Проблема состоит в следующем. Я посылаю запрос на сервер следующим образом.

```
$http({
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                mimeType: "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
                params: { groupId: groupId },
                headers: {
                    "Header-Type": "charset=UTF-8",
                    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en,ru-ru"
                }
            }).then(function (result) {
                if (result.data !== "") {
                    $scope.filterDetails = result.data;
                    filterList = decodeURIComponent(escape(result.headers("filterList")));
                    $scope.isListEmpty = false;
                } else {
                    $scope.isListEmpty = true;
                }
            }, function (result) {
                alert(result.data);
            });
```

в контроллере добавляю заголовок filterList.

```
 List<SiteFilter> result = SiteFilterRepository.GetFilterList(groupId);
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string str = serializer.Serialize(result);
            Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            Response.AppendHeader("filterList", str);
            Response.Charset = "utf-8";
            if (result != null)
            {
                return View("~/Views/SavedSearches/SavedSearchesDetails.cshtml", groupId);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("~/Views/SavedSearches/SavedSearchesDetails.cshtml", groupId);
            }
```

Который выглядит следующим образом

```
[{\"Id\":85,\"FilterGroupId\":68,\"Parameter\":\"CallId\",\"Condition\":\"Равно\",\"Value\":\"4\"}]"
```

В Google Chrome и Firefox работает нормально, но не в IE 11.В строке    `filterList = decodeURIComponent(escape(result.headers("filterList")))` выдаёт ошибку `Обнаружена недопустимая кодировка при попытке декодирования URI`.Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: а чем мотивирован такой изощренный способ возврата данных в вызывающий код?

Answer (score 0):

Решил это следующим образом.Кодирую в контроллере в escape последовательность,следующим образом.

```
 string str = serializer.Serialize(result);
                string res= HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(str);
                Response.AppendHeader("filterList", res);
```

В JavaScript декодирую escape последовательность.

```
 filterList = decodeURIComponent(result.headers("filterList"));
```